# Error: The name phonetxt does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an email form that I created using Visual Studio Community (Mac Version);
I added the following to the page header of the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="emailForm.Default" %>
```

...basically, `CodeFile=" "` was missing

...but I still get the error.

Could I get some help with this please?

Comment: why the stars? **

Comment: Remove **
`<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="emailForm.Default" %>`

Comment: There are no stars in the code, I hit a shortcut key & the stars must of generated when I was typing this message this is what I actually have:         <%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="emailForm.Default" %>

Comment: where are you getting this error? debugging or as soon as you navigate to this page

Comment: Can you show some more of your code - the phonetxt control for example, it might be helpful.

Comment: Is this a web site or application ? Are you sure that both, the codefile and inherits are pointing to the same code file/class ?